# How to make Update Query in JSP on Button Click without Reloading Window?

Tags: java, mysql, ajax, jsp, jstl

I have come across a complicated situation. I have made a dynamic app with JSP and I have added a like button for all the posts. I want to increment the like count of the respective post by clicking on the like button without reloading the page (Like AJAX). How do I do that in JSP? Is it possible with JSTL?

Sorry for not adding any code as I have currently have no idea what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use JSP/JSTL functionality for this. I guess your button is HTML element, so you can use 'onClick' event to call JavaScript function that will do AJAX request with like counter increment.

```
<button onclick="incrementLikeCounter()">Like</button>
```